# SQL: How to search two columns within a nested query?

Tags: mysql, sql, operators, dbeaver

In my DB, the ts.ID only appears in the l.origin column. I need to search both l.orgin and l.destination. Why when I query l.origin OR l.destination does it show all of the results with a ts.ID instead of only the specific ones with a ts.ID connected to Sheffield. Is there an easier way to search both columns?

```
SELECT F.name, F.phone
FROM Franchise F
WHERE F.name IN (SELECT C.companyName
FROM company c
WHERE c.routeNumber IN (SELECT c.`number`
FROM Line l
WHERE l.origin OR l.end IN (SELECT ts.ID
FROM TrainStation ts
WHERE ts.description = 'Sheffield' )));
```

Thanks for any help. Im fairly new at this.

Comment: See about JOINs

Comment: See about formatting code for readability.  Indenting goes a long way.

Comment: You are probably misunderstanding how `OR` works in your `WHERE l.origin OR l.end ...` clause: It does *not* mean "find those lines where either `origin` or `end` are in a list of trainstation ids. It rather means "find those lines where `origin` has a value or `end` is in a list of trainstation ids. Compare [the documentation of the OR operator](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/logical-operators.html#operator_or).

Answer (score 0):

Adding to Chris' comment, the `WHERE l.origin OR l.end IN ...` section can be addressed in several ways, including using a `CASE WHEN` block with each field (l.origin and l.end) tested against the condition separately, as such:

```
WHERE
  (CASE
      WHEN l.origin IN (
                       SELECT ts.ID
                       FROM TrainStation ts
                       WHERE ts.description = 'Sheffield')
      THEN 1
      WHEN l.end IN (
                       SELECT ts.ID
                       FROM TrainStation ts
                       WHERE ts.description = 'Sheffield')
      THEN 1
      ELSE 0
      END
) = 1
;
```